# fmRESTor Find Records OR or NOT operator

Tags: php, filemaker

I'm using [fmRESTor](https://www.24usoftware.com/fmRESTor/) and with my find query I'd like to use a not equals to operator or us an OR operator. I cannot seem to achieve either.

I want to find records where a field is either not equal to 1 or it is empty or equal to 0.

```
$fetchedFileMakerClients = $this->fmRESTor->getRepository(Client::FILEMAKER_BASIC_LAYOUT)->findRecords([
    'limit' => $limit,
    'query' => [
        [
            'recordId' => $firstClient['fileMakerRecordId'] . '...' . $lastClient['fileMakerRecordId'],
            'Is Inactive' => '< ' . 1,
       ],
    ],
    'portal' => [],
]);
```

So I'd like `Is Inactive` to be something like:

Is inactive not equal to 1

`'Is Inactive' => '!= 1'`

Or is inactive empty or less than 1:

`'Is Inactive' => '= OR < 1'`

How can I achieve either of these?

Comment: I am not familiar with `fmRESTor`. Glancing at the documentation [here](https://github.com/24u/fmRESTor), it seems you need to do something like `"Is Inactive" => "1", "omit" => "true"`.

Comment: Likewise I am not familiar with fmRESTor, but != is not a FileMaker logical operator, the equivalent is FileMaker is <> but you can't use <> in a find, as michael pointed out omit can work there. Just for reference here are some docs on making FileMaker finds which should let you know what text you can put inside the find (e.g. "==" is an exact match): https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Ffinding-numbers-dates-times-timestamps.html%23

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$fetchedFileMakerClients = $this->fmRESTor->getRepository(Client::FILEMAKER_BASIC_LAYOUT)->findRecords([
'limit' => $limit,
'query' => [
    [
        'recordId' => $firstClient['fileMakerRecordId'] . '...' . $lastClient['fileMakerRecordId'],
        "omit"  => "false",
   ],
    [
        'Is Inactive' => '==1',
        "omit"  => "true",
   ],
],
'portal' => [],
```

]);

By the way fmRESTor documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/24u/fmRESTor.php)